# SQL Server 2014 Standard Edition Large Table performance

Tags: sql-server, database-performance, qsqlquery

I have a question with regards to performance currently I have a table that is having trouble with query performance whenever the table rows in already millions of record.

This is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[HistorySampleValues]
(
    [HistoryParameterID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SourceTimeStamp] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [ArchiveTimestamp] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__HistorySa__Archi__2A164134]  DEFAULT (getutcdate()),
    [ValueStatus] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ArchiveStatus] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IntegerValue] [bigint] SPARSE  NULL,
    [DoubleValue] [float] SPARSE  NULL,
    [StringValue] [varchar](100) SPARSE  NULL,
    [EnumNamedSetName] [varchar](100) SPARSE  NULL,
    [EnumNumericValue] [int] SPARSE  NULL,
    [EnumTextualValue] [varchar](256) SPARSE  NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [Source_HistParameterID_Index] ON [dbo].[HistorySampleValues]
(
    [HistoryParameterID] ASC,
    [SourceTimeStamp] ASC
) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO
```

It's fairly flat with a clustered index on `HistoryParameterID` and `SourceTimeStamp`.

This is the stored procedure that I'm using

```
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
   DECLARE @SqlCommand NVARCHAR(MAX)

   SET @SqlCommand = 'SELECT HistoryParameterID, 
                            SourceTimestamp, ArchiveTimestamp,ValueStatus,ArchiveStatus,
                            IntegerValue,DoubleValue,StringValue,EnumNumericValue,
                            EnumTextualValue,EnumNamedSetName 
                        FROM [HistorySampleValues] WITH(NOLOCK) 
                        WHERE ([HistoryParameterID] =' + @ParamIds + '
                        AND
                        [SourceTimeStamp] >= ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),@StartTime, 25) + '''
    AND           
    [SourceTimeStamp] <= ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),@EndTime, 25) + ''') 
    AND ValueStatus = ' + @ValueStatus 

    EXECUTE( @SqlCommand )
```

As you can see the `HistoryParameterID` and `SourceTimestamp` are being used as the parameters for the first query. And retrieving 8hrs worth of records which is ~28k records, it returns with an erratic performance, 1.8seconds - 700ms

Will the design scale? whenever it reaches 77 billion records? or is there any strategy to be used? the version of SQL Server is Standard Edition so there is no partitioning, columnstore to be used. Or have I reached the maximum performance of SQL Server Standard Edition?

---

this is the updated stored proc

```
 @ParamIds int,
    @StartTime datetime,
    @EndTime datetime,
    @ValueStatus int 
AS
BEGIN
       SET NOCOUNT ON;
       SELECT HistoryParameterID, 
        SourceTimestamp, ArchiveTimestamp,ValueStatus,ArchiveStatus,
        IntegerValue,DoubleValue,StringValue,EnumNumericValue,
        EnumTextualValue,EnumNamedSetName 
        FROM [HistorySampleValues] WITH(NOLOCK) 
        WHERE 
        HistoryParameterID = @ParamIds
        AND (SourceTimeStamp >= @StartTime AND SourceTimeStamp <=@EndTime)
        AND (@ValueStatus = -1 OR ValueStatus = @ValueStatus)
```

I got a 1.396 second client processing time in retrieving 41213 rows to a ~849600000 rows in the table.

is there a way to improve this?

Comment: curious to know why dynamic query?

Comment: based on testing,  i was able to improve performance using dynamic query compared to the others

Comment: Parameters will give you better results if you plan to reuse the query.

Comment: @OliverTownshend can you elaborate more on the parameters?

Comment: SELECT *
FROM HistorySampleValues
WHERE HistorySampleValueID = @ParamIds AND .... is this Parameters you are talking about? but based on testing the dynamic query was faster

Comment: if i do this will i have a consistent performance? preferably less than a second when retrieving 28k rows in billion of rows?

Comment: I think you should take the test on @valuestatus out of the query and put it into an IF statement:

Comment: if (@@ValueStatus=1)
       SELECT ....
        AND (SourceTimeStamp >= @@StartTime AND SourceTimeStamp <=@@EndTime)
    else
       SELECT ....
        AND (SourceTimeStamp >= @@StartTime AND SourceTimeStamp <=@@EndTime)
        AND (ValueStatus = @@ValueStatus)

Comment: with "I got a 1.396 second client processing time in retrieving 41213 rows" are you talking about a client directly running on the database server or a client connected over a network?

Comment: there are in the same machine a .Net client accesssing the database server within the same machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everytime you execute a new SQL command, it has to be compiled by the MS SQL Server.  If you re-use the command, you save on compilation time.  You need to directly execute the command in the stored procedure something like this, which should allow compilation and give you more consistent results.

```
SELECT ... 
WHERE ([HistoryParameterID] = @ParamIds 
AND [SourceTimeStamp] >= @StartTime
AND [SourceTimeStamp] <= @EndTime 
AND ValueStatus = @ValueStatus
```

This will give you also an opportunity to monitor the performance of the command.

Comment: BTW, you have any idea on what is the performance of SQL Server in terms on queryies? can it handle the scenario that will experience for standard edition without partiioning?

Comment: Hi Oliver, tried you suggestion and i tried doing it with 2 application retrieving ~28k records at the same time. i got a 2sec average it is quite slow.

Comment: Have you tried changing the type of StartTime and EndTime to be datetime2 rather than strings?  You also want to use the "Display Estimated Execution Plan" in SQL Management Studio to get a picture of whats happening.

Comment: i used your suggestion, but i got a performance I got a 1.396 second client processing time in retrieving 41213 rows to a ~849600000 rows in the table.

is there a way to improve this?

Comment: How does performance go with multiple runs with different parameters?  Does performance improve or stay linear?

Are you able to generate the proposed plan for the query?

Comment: yes it is always at clustered index seek. the performance are the same with differnt parameters (randomize in the HistoryParameterID) it is quite linear and it just plays around 1.3-2 seconds which i think is acceptable already.